# Why body width don't set to 100% on browser window resize?

Tags: html, css

For example let's take a look for main page of Twitter bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

If I resize browser window to 400px I will see strange space on the right (look at the picture).

[image]

Another sample is StackOverflow. On browser resize header line with gray background don't resize to all screen (see below).

[image]

Why body don't resize to 100% of the browser window? I have a similar problem on my site

Comment: Yes what browser is that? Also not having that issue.

Answer (score 5):

The issue happens when you make the browser window smaller than the minimum width of the content and horizontally scroll. Elements that are set to 100% width are 100% of the width, until you scroll horizontally, where they appear to be cut off.

The solution is to set a `min-width` on those elements so they are at least as wide as the content.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<div id="header1">Broken header</div>
<div id="header2">Fixed header</div>
<div id="content">
  content goes here.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header1 {
  background-color:#ccc;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
}

#header2 {
  background-color:#ddd;
  min-width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #0F0;
}

#content {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #F00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ifinix/1)

Similar questions:

- [100% width bg images not extending on horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042979/100-width-bg-images-not-extending-on-horizontal-scroll)
- [CSS: background absent when scrolling horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426050/css-background-absent-when-scrolling-horizontally)
- [Footer not stretching 100% when horizontally scrolled](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/footer-not-stretching-100-when-horizontally-scrolled)
- [How can I avoid my headers and footers being broken when displaying content wider than the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226376/how-can-i-avoid-my-headers-and-footers-being-broken-when-displaying-content-wide)